# javascript array, object, key:value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Select all the values of objects in the array. For example,

```js
tutorials = [{title:a, movie:a}, {title:b, movie:b}, {title:c, movie:c}] => a b c.
```

I want to find the values of the titles of all objects.

`Tutorials[number].title` was attempted, but it was impossible to obtain the value of the title of all objects.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zohrab's answer is correct. I am just showing an alternative way:

```
let tutorials = [
    {
        title:'a', movie:'a'
    },
    {
        title:'b', movie:'b'
    }, 
    {
        title:'c', movie:'c'
    }
]

const titles = [];
for (tutorial of tutorials) {
  titles.push(tutorial.title)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const titles = tutorials.map(t => t.title)
```

Will do the job in one line

Answer (score 1):

You can use *for loop* for this here is the example:

```js
let tutorials = [
    {
        title:'a', movie:'a'
    },
    {
        title:'b', movie:'b'
    }, 
    {
        title:'c', movie:'c'
    }
]

for(let i = 0; i < tutorials.length; i++) {
    console.log(tutorials[i].title);
}
```